# Is there a way to get the typed CSS and not the computed style?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to get the CSS rules for an HTML element.

I already found an answer here: [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

The problem is that the given answer doesen't work, as it is stated in the comments; it gives me `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button.ui-button::-moz-focus-inner`

The problem in that code is that it is passing every CSS rule selector to the `jquery.is()` method, that is probably unable to recognise '`every`' CSS selector that can be written, so it gives an error on complicated rules.

I've searched around and looked at the standard but I'm running out of ideas.

There is another answer that gives the computed style, that is what I am using currently, but that is giving me so many useless properties that are damaging my result.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You should post this answer to the original question, then.

Comment: I can't, not enough reputation.. i will when i will get it :)

Comment: Ok, good job resolving your own question!

Comment: You should be able to move your edit into an answer and mark it accepted now! Someone just bumped your question with an "answer" complimenting your solution, which I've removed now, as we really don't want that sort of thing in place of an actual answer :)

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to do it. Did it just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it this way: I modified the code from [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)
to this one:

```
function css(a){
   var o = {};
   var rules = window.getMatchedCSSRules(a.get(0));
   for(var r in rules) {
         o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
   }
   return o;
}




function css2json(css){
        var s = {};
        if(!css) return s;
        if(css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
            for(var i in css) {
                if((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                    s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
                }
            }
        } else if(typeof css == "string") {
            css = css.split("; ");          
            for (var i in css) {
                var l = css[i].split(": ");
                s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            };
        }
        return s;
    }
```